# Convert a recordSet object into a JSON array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm fetching a recordSet from a SQL query and I'm trying to transpose that into a JS array object quickly(around 4000 rows in the query result).

I'd be using this Javascript object to iterate over to get some info to feed into a different object.
 In a different post here, someone suggested using getRows() method for fetching the data quickly, but due to the nature of arrays in  Javascript, it's becoming hard to convert that into desired JS object.

Here's what I have so far.

```html
function ExportDataToJSObject()
{

  //Connection String
  var  conn  = ADOConnectionObj.CreateADOConnection();
   conn.ConnectionString = "ConnectionString with Params"                     
   conn.Open();

  var Results = conn.Execute_("SELECT * from EMP_DETAILS"); 
   var tempArray = Results.GetRows();

   //temp array I got is: 
   // ["John","Jane","Logy", 45, 25, 21, "GM", "Reception", "Janitor", "ON","OFF" "ON"]

   // convert the tempArray into desired JS Object       

}
```

Here's what I'm trying to get in the output:

```html
var EmpObj = [
  { EmpName: "John", Age: 45, Title: "GM", InTime: "ON"},
  { EmpName: "Jane", Age: 25, Title: "Recepition", InTime: "OFF"},
  { EmpName: "Logy", Age: 21, Title: "Janitor", InTime: "ON"}
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

ANC

Comment: JSON is a string format, like CSV or XML. Your output is not valid JSON. It's valid JavaScript, but not valid JSON. See https://json.org

Comment: please add `tempArray`.

Comment: I added tempArray

Comment: which server language are you using?

Comment: Node. js (JavaScript)  if that helps

Comment: do you get an array of the column names as well?

Comment: Nope. GetRows() method doesn't fetch any columns. I tried to fetch the column names separately, and data using the getRows(), I couldn't  combine it to form a JS object that I need( as shown above) . Here's more info on GetRows() method for recordSet  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-getrows-method-dao

Comment: We have a few questions around converting a DataSet to JSON. If I remember correctly, there's a way of filling a DataSet from a RecordSet...

Comment: Do you have always 4 fields named "EmpName", "Age", "Title" and "Intime"?

Comment: nope. It just depends on the SQL query I would use  in  " conn.Execute_("SELECT * from EMP_DETAILS")" statement. Another query might have 10 fields that I'd fetch in the recordSet